# Referencing other projects in xml file Android

Tags: android

I have imported a android project in my eclipse workspace,but I see it has following code in its xml file :

```
../../../SalesforceSDK/res/values/sdk.xml
```

so I have imported the `SalesforceSDK` project also in same workspace.Still I can not build my project.When I change something in xml (removing some of the ../) file, eclipse shows red error mark.

How to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if its in the same workspace.. as in.. SalesforceSDK and YourProject are in the same folder.. your reference to SalesforceSDK should look like

`android.library.reference.1=..\\SalesforceSDK`

in project.properties  ..

You should just be setting this in Eclipse (right click on project properties -> Android -> Click "add" under Library.. and then select your SalesforceSDK) instead of manually editing the XML file